# Which design pattern fit for this scenario C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, design-patterns

I am working on an C# MVC application. I have a scenario where I want to know which design patter will be best fit for it.

The scenario is:

I have to perform some sequence of steps for an entity. Like:

```
Step-1 Entity Created
Step-2 Entity Approved
Step-3 Entity Assigned to someone
Step-4 Entity Publish
..
....
```

These steps are configured means at any point of time admin can switch on/off some non-mandatory steps. Like:

If admin switched off step-2 then after step-1 I need to move directly on step-3.

Can anyone please help me to identify the design pattern for the above mentioned scenario.

Thanks

Comment: The visitor or chain of command pattern may work for you.

Comment: Read Gang of 4. Implement all of them, then tell us which is the best one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first design pattern that comes to my mind is [State](http://www.dofactory.com/net/state-design-pattern). You can make each state have a `GetNextState()` (or similar) method which does the necessary checking and returns the corresponding following state.

Answer (score 1):

That's a workflow in my opinion.  Microsoft has a Workflow Engine:  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-deed2cd5

With a workflow you can create Step1, Step2, Step3, as workflow actions and steps can be disabled and reenabled etc.

You also get a neat xaml based Workflow Designer.  There is example code on the link I posted.

Comment: Here's another article on integrating a persisted workflow in mvc 4+.  https://stevenwilliamalexander.wordpress.com/2010/11/16/integrating-a-persisted-wf40-workflow-with-mv/

Comment: Also as another note, if you'rw going to ever touch sharepoint with this stuff, workflows are cool because you can take your workflow foundation workflows and use them in sharepoint and attach them to lists and stuff and use list data to run through your workflow.

If you are not using sharepoint (ever) then consider just rolling you're own state machine as @Andrew suggested for simplicity.   Workflow's are nice, but there is a lot to learn and implement there and they can get pretty complex.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) with some state parameters.

```
abstract class AbsFoo {
    public abstract void Step1();
    public abstract void Step2();
    public abstract void Step3();
    public abstract void Step4();

    public void process(bool doStep1, 
                        bool doStep2,
                        bool doStep3,
                        bool doStep4) {
        if (doStep1) Step1();
        if (doStep2) Step2();
        if (doStep3) Step3();
        if (doStep4) Step4();
    }
}

class ConcreteFoo : AbsFoo {
    public override void Step1() {
        Console.WriteLine("Do something in step 1.");
    }
    public override void Step2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do something in step 2.");
    }
    public override void Step3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do something in step 3.");
    }
    public override void Step4()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do something in step 4.");
    }
}
```

Then in client class, you can call the method in base class.

```
class Client {
    static void Main() {
        AbsFoo foo = new ConcreteFoo();

        foo.process(true, false, true, true);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

However, if the states become more and more, you may consider combine [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) with this.

Comment: why do you need to pass `doStepN` to the `process` method? In future if you want to add step5, step6, step7, you will need to modify the `process` method too. **If you don't want to execute any step, just leave it empty in the concrete class.**

Comment: @kienct89 Because by passing `doStepN` to the `process` method, one can dynamically decide which method is called during the program running. For example, I may set the `doStepN` based on user input. If you leave the method empty in concrete class, you cannot call it when the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand your question correctly;

Event-Driven programming may be of interest to you; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx

You can design your 'step' code as modules, allow flags to be turned on and off from a 'control center' and raise events according to what steps needed to be taken.

This also leaves room to multi-thread steps (if you choose to develop modules, and can guarantee that they are orthogonal).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `template method` design pattern for this situation.

It **ensures the execution order**, provide the ability to **switch off** one or more steps.

Reference: http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a state machine type situation to me where steps are your state objects, and where each state may have multiple exit transitions based on conditions (such as options currently on). The State will then stand in for the C in MVC.

A discussion of the pattern can be found here [with a focus on game programming](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html) with other examples available.

A state pattern will essentially will allow you you create a graph and, more importantly, allow each edge of the graph to be assigned behavior with will cause the edge to be followed.

so in your case the graph could be defined in this made up scheme I just came up with as:

```
[state] => [transition-to] (condition)
1 => 3 (if opt_go_to_3 == true)
1 => 2 
2 => 3
2 => 5 (if some_other_optioon == true)
2 => 3
... (etc)
```

Now your code is nicely objectified but still pretty flexible. When it comes to the behavior you need to run based on condition.

Now if use this state object as the controller in your MVC scheme it actually all fits together pretty nice.

Your state machine's current state can create the new views on enter based on some model data.

Speaking about that model data, its not a great idea to hard code that into the state machine infrastructure as it makes everything pretty clunky pretty fast.

Instead think of using a blackboard-ing or message boarding type interface. This idea says that every state should have an interface to write a message to an object.

This can be done using delegates in C#, passing an object to every state when its created, or any other pattern that will give all states in the machine access to this "global" resource.

The idea of the board is that a states may post data to it, for example the results of some computation or the value of some user input. Then later another state running might choose to read a message for a useful value.